# NPM module throws an error when being imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, npm, webpack

I have been trying to get the following module to work on a react/webpack application:

https://github.com/ripjar/material-datetime-picker

Whenever I import the module my server wont start and it crashes with the syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.

It seems that throughout the modules code it is using es6 to import/export but each one of those lines breaks the module when I try to install and export it into my own file.

I have tried looking through the source code for the module as well as the standalone version but cant get either to work - however - I know that the module works inside a standalone HTML file as their demo still works when I download it locally.

Could this have to do with incompatibility with webpack? I have been working with their code along with a senior developer and we cant seem to get the module to load at all.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have babel configured properly. Make sure the es2015 preset is enabled.

Comment: i have that preset on my own application. im importing quite a bit of modules as well. the syntax error occurs on the import inside the source code for that module

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're trying to import es6 module while not using es6 compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

If you intend to use it with CommonJS you should consider adding it using `require`:

```
var MaterialDateTimePicker = require('material-datetime-picker');
```

Comment: i am using a babgel compiler for my code and im importing es6 modules throughout my project. the actual error comes from the source code of the module itself, not my code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using this module/js for front-end(browser). I will suggest using babelify in your build environment. You can check documentation in given links.

> [webpack-for-browserify-users](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-for-browserify-users.html)
>
> [babeljs.io-installation](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation)
>
> [babel/babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify)

Babel transformation--

```
var fs = require("fs"); var browserify = require("browserify");
var babelify = require("babelify");

browserify({ debug: true })   
    .transform(babelify)   
    .require("./script.js", { entry: true })   
    .bundle()   
    .on("error", function (err) { 
        console.log("Error: " + err.message); 
    }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("bundle.js"));
```